# SonarQube 5.2 exclusions not found

Tags: sonarqube

I just updated from SonarQube LTS to SonarQube 5.2 and I cannot find neither global nor per-project exclusions.

According to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus I should look for them under:

> Settings > General Settings > Exclusions
>
> Configuration > Settings > Exclusions

but I have neither Settings, nor Configuration and in the left menu "CATEGORY" I have not an "Exclusions" link.

I can see the exclusions from the database and they are used during the analysis, but I'd expect to change them from the UI instead of the database :)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This documentation seems not have been up to date (could be announced on [SonarQube forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)).

In SonarQube 5.2, exclusions are in :

```
Administration (global or per project) > [Configuration > General Settings] > Analysis Scope > Files
```